# The separated twins

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> We are twins
>   With the same name
>   We live in different states
>   So we are not the same
>
> Folks will tell you we are
>   Close to a cotton-field
>   But that's a lie
>   That must be repealed

Who (or what) are we?

Comment: Are they _ice_ and _dry  ice_ as they exist in two different forms and they look white in colour.

Comment: That's not the direction I was thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is:

> Texarkana

Explanation:

First part:

> There is a Texarkana city in Texas and in Arkansas

Second part:

> There is a song (folk) that mentions it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_Fields

Comment: That is right! Much faster than I thought.

Comment: It would be nice to explain the verse "But that's a lie"... But I'm accepting this answer as it is.

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken The "But that's a lie" is in the lyrics part in the wikipedia page, I can put that here, but the whole second part is in the wikipedia page =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> <s>Kansas City? There is a Kansas City in both Kansas and Missouri.</s> Arlington? There is an Arlington in VA and TX, the one in TX being the location for the Cotton Bowl.

Comment: Wow! That was really close... but look at the other clues!

Comment: I took a second shot at it!